# How to update row with blob data in sqlite3?

Tags: python, sqlite, byte, blob

I'm trying to update existing row in my database with blob data, and cannot understand how to do this. Is it only insert aviliable? Insert works well:

```
b = requests.get(url=url)
img = b.content
con = sqlite3.connect(db)
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute('replace INTO byte(b) where n = 1 VALUES (?)', [img])
con.commit()
con.close()
```

this give my new row with blob data, but I need to update existing, but if i try some update code it gives me errors:

```
cur.execute('update byte set b = {}'.format(img))
```

Comment: [Edit] your Question and show your `CREATE TABLE` statement and the given errors as well.

Comment: Well I found the way. At first convert byte to hex string and update db with it, then select hex and convert to byte. So the question may be closed.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well I found the way. At first convert byte to hex string and update db with it, then select hex and convert to byte. So the question may be closed.